# Can't find class StoredProfileAWSCredentials using AWS SDK v3 for C#

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I can't find the class StoredProfileAWSCredentials. I've got AWSSDK.Core and AWSSDK.APIGateway added via NuGet in Visual Studio 2015 (both are v3). I'm trying to new up an instance of StoredProfileAWSCredentials so that I can specify the credential I'm looking for (as defined in my credentials file). From the docs, this class is in the "Amazon.Runtime" namespace, and I'm doing a "using Amazon.Runtime;". But the compiler keeps telling me that the class doesn't exist.

If I type the fully qualified name to browse the list, starting with Amazon.Runtime and filtering by the word "credentials", I see its parent class, AWSCredentials, but I can't find the actual class, StoredProfileAWSCredentials.

There must be something super obvious that I'm missing here, where does this class exist and what do I need to do to access it?

UPDATE:
I have the following packages added via NuGet:
AWSSDK.APIGateway v3.3.4 and AWSSDK.Core v3.3.7.1.

Answer (score 1):

Its In the `Amazon.Runtime.StoredProfileAWSCredentials`. The assembly is in `ASWSDK.Core.DLL`.

I've used it in conjunction with the [S3 sdk](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AWSSDK.S3/). That seems to work. Based on what I understand about the docs. Apparently, Core is bundled with other assemblies when ref'd for a specific reason.

## Update

After looking at the source I found that it does live in the Core assembly.

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/5ddd7712e982ef81b3fb5ba446dde834955a679d/sdk/src/Core/Amazon.Runtime/AWSCredentials.cs

Nuget acts weird sometimes. Perhaps you should try uninstalling and re-installing the nuget lib. Also, could you tell me **exactly** what is the **nuget package name** and **version**?

## Update

You should not have to install both the core and the APIGateway. Try Just installing the 1 package AWSSDK.APIGateway v3.3.4 and let the dependency management handle the core.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, had to eat. I have these 2 AWS packages added via NuGet: AWSSDK.APIGateway v3.3.4 and AWSSDK.Core v3.3.7.1. Also I just tried uninstalling and reinstalling and nothing changed. I still don't see that class in Amazon.Runtime. I see AWSCredentials (and others) but not StoredProfileAWSCredentials.

Comment: In fact, when I use the object browser and look at the AWSSDK.Core assembly, I don't see the class either.

Comment: I wonder if the problem is NuGet. If I make a new project and use the templated empty AWS project it auto adds the SDK which I had installed and is located in my Program Files (x86) directory. By default, it has AWSSDK.Core added as a reference, and in that one, I do in fact see the missing class! But if I make a new project and add AWSSDK.Core via NuGet, the class is missing. I was under the impression from their docs that the preferred way to do it is to use NuGet since it gets  updated more frequently. The version in this case is v3.3.0.0

Comment: Hmmm..... strange. The latest version of the docs also has it referenced. 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/Runtime/TRuntimeStoredProfileAWSCredentials.html

Comment: Hmm maybe I'm wrong about the version from my Program Files directory. When I view the properties of the DLL from within VS it says "Version 3.3.0.0" but if look at the file version in the folder directly, it shows 3.3.7.1. It also shows this up to date version in the Reference Manager. Regardless, this seems to fix the problem...but I'm really confused as to why the version obtained via NuGet would be missing classes, especially since the version numbers profess to be the same.

Comment: In response to your last update regarding installing the 1 package, I just made a completely new blank Xamarin project (not forms). I went to NuGet and installed AWSSDK.APIGateway and as expected it also installed Core. Upon using the object browser, same thing: class doesn't exist.

Comment: Update: StoredProfileAWSCredentials is depreciated
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/600